# Set Manager property exception when Manager's OU name contains special characters

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Manager's DN looks like

```
CN=managerName, OU=test/SubTest, OU=ouName, CN=domainName,CN=com
```

When trying to set the `manager` property causes an exception.

Do you have a correct format if manager's OU contains `/` or `@` special characters?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **escape** those special characters with a backslash `\` - change your manager's DN from

```
CN=managerName, OU=test/SubTest, OU=ouName, CN=domainName,CN=com
```

to

```
CN=managerName, OU=test\/SubTest, OU=ouName, CN=domainName,CN=com
```

and then you should be fine.

See [Characters to escape](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm) for a complete list of all problematic characters that need to be escaped in a LDAP DN.